# Showing white screen after splash screen in blackberry phonegap

Tags: cordova, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a blackberry phonegap application.Application is working fine but when i launching application after splash screen a white screen is showing for few seconds. 
Can anybody help me to remove this white screen?
Thanks  in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I've seen this happen is when an app is say, downloading assets from a web server (which is holding up the reset of the app from loading).

What are you doing in your index html file?  Are you pulling any resources in from a remote server?

If not, perhaps there's something going on in the onDeviceReady function that's holding up the app.  It would be a good spot to start debugging from.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have seen a problem like this, it has usually been a permanent white screen and been caused by an untrapped exception in the JavaScript code, meaning that the UI does not manage to finish updating.

Like chadtatro said, it looks like something is taking up all your processor time during initialisation.  Is your code getting as far as onDeviceReady, or is an onLoad event for your page causing a problem before Cordova initialises?

Comment: ya i am using code function onDeviceReady() { 
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backKeyDown, true);   
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function backKeyDown() {
    /*document.body.style.cursor = 'none';*/
    jConfirm('Are you sure you want to exit?', 'Confirm', function(r) {     
        if (r == true) {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }    
    });       
} in our application.I have tried to remove this code but still white screen showing after splash screen.please help me to solve my problem